# What does connectAs="endUser" actually do?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

The Worklight documentation [refers to an attribute](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr__procedure_.html&resultof%3D%2522%2563%256f%256e%256e%2565%2563%2574%2561%2573%2522%2520%2522%2563%256f%256e%256e%2565%2563%2574%2561%2522%2520) within the  element of an adapter's XML file called `connectAs="endUser"`. It says that this means that:

> The connection to the back end is created with the user’s identity.
>   Only valid if a user realm has been identified in the security tests
>   for this procedure.

However, what does this actually mean in terms of the HTTP connection that is performed from the adapter to the back-end HTTP server? How does it affect, for example, the JSESSIONID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: Further to my original post, Anton Aleksandrov has provided a blog post with more details on how this mechanism works:**
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_http_adapters_for_stateless_stateful_backend_connectivity_and_user_identity_propagation?lang=en

---

What this actually means is that the Worklight server will behave as if it were an "end user" (specifically, a web browser).

Within a given Worklight adapter, the connectAs="endUser" parameter will result in the HTTP Set-Cookie headers being stored as part of an authenticated Worklight session. Subsequent requests that request connectAs="endUser" will send any cookies that are stored as part of that "endUser" server-side session.

The Worklight documentation specifically states that it is only valid in a realm has been identified since if there is no realm, it is not possible to save those cookies for later use in the server-side session.

The effect from a Worklight client app point of view should not change if you choose to use this parameter.

The Worklight server to back end HTTP services will change. Essentially the back end server will treat a Worklight adapter that uses connectAs="endUser" as a single HTTP web browser. So for the example of JSESSIONID:

1. You initiate a procedure "**login**" for the first time that specifies **connectAs="endUser"**. This procedure also has an associated security test which enforces a user to be logged into a realm (by whatever means, or anonymous - it doesn't really matter so long as Worklight has a user session to attach cookies to)
2. When this request reaches a Java-based server that tracks sessions by JSESSIONID, it will detect that this is a first-time request. It will process the request, and send a HTTP response, with whatever content is necessary in the HTTP body. In the HTTP headers, there will be a Set-Cookie response that contains a JSESSIONID.
3. By virtue of the Worklight procedure having contained connectAs="endUser", the Worklight server will process these Set-Cookie headers and store them alongside the session of the user authorised against the Worklight realm (this is why you need to have a realm that is logged in for this to work)
4. On a subsequent request to a procedure "**mySecondServerProcedure**", which also has **connectAs="endUser"** and the same realm specified, the Worklight server will automatically provide the stored cookies to the server on the outgoing HTTP request, in addition to any you add as parameters on a requestHttp() call in your adapter. In this example, the JSESSIONID that was set as part of "login" will be provided.
5. If you make another request to a procedure "**myThirdServerProcedure**" that does **NOT** have connectAs="endUser" set, no cookies will be provided to the server on the outgoing HTTP response that you do not provide manually as part of the "Cookies" parameters on the requestHttp() call in your adapter.

**Important points to note:**

- A user must be logged in for this to work so that Worklight can associate the HTTP cookies with a session
- The session cookie storage is only valid WITHIN the adapter that made the initial request; if you run a connectAs="endUser" request from another adapter after having gotten your JSESSIONID set as part of "login" above, this request will NOT have the JSESSIONID cookie automatically appended to the outgoing request.
- If you log out of the authenticated Worklight user session, all reference to these cookies will be gone.

My general rule of thumb is as follows:

- If you are doing some fairly simple authentication that requires cookies on the back-end server to remain consistent, use endUser
- If you're doing something more complex, or potentially requiring the cookies sent by the server to be available from multiple adapters, find another way to store the cookies. A pattern I like is to have a wrapper method present that makes the outgoing HTTP request and processes the headers that come back in the response to store necessary "global" properties somewhere. In the Worklight world, this can either be as part of a Worklight user session object, or you can call out to an underlying Java or database storage implementation.