# MobileFirst Adapter Cookie Policy

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

There is something confusing about MobileFirst adapters which is the Cookie policy. Actually I can't find any documentation specifying the detailed use of each kind Cookie policy and how is it related to connectAs attribute.
I have this concern because each time I have to authenticate to a third party application, I get in many troubles while maintaining Cookies and third party session.

Is there someone who could explain it in details please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [user documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_http_adapter_connect_pol.html) for the `connectionPolicy` element of a HTTP adapter, you are expected to read about each `cookiePolicy` in its specific RFC - because these cookie policies aren't IBM's. They are industry standards:

- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt
- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt
- http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html

See also here: [What does the cookiePolicy adapter parameter do in Worklight 6.1+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627148/what-does-the-cookiepolicy-adapter-parameter-do-in-worklight-6-1)

> These cookies don't affect the JSESSIONID cookie returned by the
>   application server to the client (mobile app). The policy relates to
>   all the cookies returned by the backend server to Worklight, including
>   JSESSIONID.

The `cookiePolicy` does not have a direct relation to the `connectAs` attribute. Because this attribute will basically dictate if there is a single HttpClient for all sessions, or an HttpClient for each session.

In either case the cookie policy is applied to the adapter.

From the same question:

> ... each adapter has a separate instance of an HttpClient, and so the
>   cookiePolicy acts only within the scope of one adapter. Different
>   adapters will not share cookies by configuration.

About `connectAs` in greater detail: [What does connectAs="endUser" actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627043/what-does-connectas-enduser-actually-do)

Comment: Hi Idan, thanks for the hint. Actually I didn't knew that the cookie policy is related to the apache Http client. The link that you sent was very helpful